# .refresh file path for 32 bit and 64 bit machines

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

In our environment, we have 32-bit and 64-bit machines for development.  In VS 2010, when a reference to a dll is added, a refresh file is getting created which points to path of the dll.  On 32 bit machines, the path used to be `<drive>:\Program Files\ ....`
but for 64 bit machines, it is `<drive>:\Program Files <x86)\.....`

The refresh files are under Source Control (subversion) so if I change the dll for a 64-bit machine, the build starts failing for 32 bit machines.  Is there a way to make these refresh files change as per the system architecture?

Is there a different way to handle this?  One way I am thinking is to not include the refresh files under Source Control but that would mean that anytime we upgrade our dll's, we need to change the dll's on each machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave the refresh files 'as-is' and store both architectures in a `\lib` directory.

```
MyLibrary.dll  // (refresh target)
MyLibrary.dll.x86
MyLibrary.dll.x64
```

Whenever I need to switch architectures I execute a build script (or batch file) that simply copies & overwrites all refresh target DLLs within my `\lib`. For example, when switching to x64, `MyLibrary.dll.x64` gets copied as (and overwrites) `MyLibrary.dll`.